# Reorder array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB, and trying to reorder an array in a db.

Here's the schema:

```
headline: String,
Galleryslides: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Galleryslide'}],
```

Here's the logic I'm using. By the way, correctOrder is an array with the new order of ids for the DB.

```
Gallery.findById(req.params.galleryId, function(err, gallery) {
    var newArr = [];
    req.body.ids.forEach(function(id, index) {
        newArr[index] = Galleryslides.find({"_id" : id});
    });
    gallery.Galleryslides = newArr;
    gallery.save(function() {
        res.json({status: 'ok'});
    });
});
```

When this runs, nothing happens - the order of the array in the DB does not change. D'you know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb, the records are sorted in [natural order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order). You should get them in the same order you inserted but that's not guaranteed.

Like the docs say :

> This ordering is an internal implementation feature, and you should
>   not rely on any particular structure within it.

If you want to sort by the `_id` field, you can do that(it will sort by the _id index) :

```
Gallery.find().sort({ "_id": 1 })
```